# when use asp:RequiredFieldValidator refresh page before check validation

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I use asp:requiredfieldvalidator but when i click on my button first my form has refresh after taht show error of required field! what is cause of this problem?

Comment: Yes my problem is just that when i click on my button form runat server before check validation

Comment: Can you show us your code?